# La alineacion horizontal de los text field en los sub reportes de jasperreport no funciona

Tags: jasper-reports, jasper

Hola amigos tengo el siguiente problema, tengo un repote principal y varios sub reportes, cuando compilo cada uno por separado todo funciona bien, las alineacion horizontal esta correcta y mis textos estan centrados o a la derecha segun como los he definido, pero cuando ejecuto el reporte principal con un subreporte se pierden las alineaciones y todo sale por defecto a la izquierda.

he buscado por horas pero no encuentro la solucion, alguien sabe si se debe pasar algun parametro o hay alguna opcion que falte activar?

uso jasperreport studio 6.0.0

espero me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el problema estaba en los .jar que usaba para compilar los reportes en mi aplicacion, ya que eran de la 6.3.0, solo los cambie a las 6.0.0 y listo.